# Word Translation by letter/vowels

Tags: c#, java, string, language-agnostic, nlp

I'm looking to translate words by letters/vowels.
I'll try to explain.
I have a an Arabic text with ~300,000 words, my goal is to enable users to search the text using one of 10 languages I'll define. So if some search for Stack overflow in English I'll need to break down to words as S-TA-CK O-VE-R-F-LOW (I need to break it that way to get the Arabic equivalent letters).
Is there something like that already exsiting, or I just need to start from scratch and do a linguistic research???
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to analyze your words by finding the relative **syllables**. Take a look at [Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4) Java library, I guess there are some example codes for extracting a word to its syllables based on defined grammar rules.